# Does hbase Import/Export command do bulk uploads?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I cannot figure out if the Import/Export `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import`/`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export` tool packaged with hbase does bulkuploads or not?

Answer (score 0):

Export is used to dump the contents of HBase file into sequence file. Import used the above file to load the data back to HBase. Both are Map reduce jobs completly. I think these processes involve WAL files(files generated in between) to be generated, as part of overall read/write steps. You can get more information [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/)

BulkLoad is a separate usecase. It is for bulk loading of data. The main reason for reduced times to bulk load is because they deal directly with HFiles and avoid the WAL files generated in between a regular write step. We use mapreduce to generate HFile and then add these files to cluster. As you can see this is a two step process and mapreduce is used in step 1. You can get more information [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/)